# In Objective-C, how to detect if multiple threads are accessing the method?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

In Objective-C, we know that @synchronized can be used to define a critical section, but is there a way to know if multiple threads are accessing a method or code block?

Comment: Is this for debugging purpose?

Comment: You can check the [NSThread currentThread] instance (you also have the [NSThread mainThread] if you need it...)

Comment: Yes for debugging. This is to check during development to make sure I didn't add in an unnecessary @synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `NSLock` object ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and test the lock using `tryLock`:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSLock *_lock;
}
...

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (id)init
{
    ...
    _lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (BOOL)myMethod
{
    if (![_lock tryLock])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to acquire lock");
        return NO;
    }

    // Thread has exclusive access
    // Caution; the lock won't be automatically unlocked if this method throws an exception
    // so add some exception handling here to ensure it's always unlocked...
    @try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    @finally
    {
        [_lock unlock];
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks.  What check should I use for @synchronized?

Comment: @Boon There isn't one.  `@synchronized` will generate `pthread_mutex` code that will always attempt to lock, and there is no way, other than using something similar to my answer, to perform a try-lock, which is what I believe you are looking for.